# Setting memory consumption limits with Upstart

Tags: process, limit, upstart, memory-consumption

I've recently become quite fond of Upstart. Previously I've been using God, Monit and Bluepill but I don't really like these solutions so I'm giving Upstart a try.

I've been using the Foreman gem to generate some basic Upstart configuration files for my processes in `/etc/init`. However, these generated files only handle the respawning of a crashed process. I was wondering whether it's possible to tell Upstart to restart a process that's consuming for example `> 150mb` of memory, as you would with Monit, God or Bluepill.

I read through the [Upstart docs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas) and [this](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#limit) looks like the thing I'm looking for. Though I have no clue how to config something like this.

What I basically want is quite simple. I want to restart my `web` process if the memory usage is `> 150mb` ram. These are the files I have:

```
|-- myapp-web-1.conf
|-- myapp-web-2.conf
|-- myapp-web-3.conf
|-- myapp-web.conf
|-- myapp.conf
```

And their contents are:

**myapp.conf**

```
pre-start script

bash << "EOF"
  mkdir -p /var/log/myapp
  chown -R deployer /var/log/myapp
EOF

end script
```

**myapp-web.conf**

```
start on starting myapp
stop on stopping myapp
```

**myapp-web-1.conf** / **myapp-web-2.conf** / **myapp-web-3.conf**

```
start on starting myapp-web
stop on stopping myapp-web
respawn

exec su - deployer -c 'cd /var/applications/releases/20110607140607; cd myapp && bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT >> /var/log/myapp/web-1.log 2>&1'
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appending this to the end of `myapp-web-*.conf` will cause any allocation calls trying to allocate more than `150mb` of memory to return `ENOMEM`:

```
limit rss 157286400 157286400
```

The process might crash at this point, or it might not. That's up to the process!

[Here's a test for this in the Upstart Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/lucid/upstart/lucid/view/head:/init/tests/test_parse_job.c#L6705).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm not too familiar with all of this but if I understand correctly, my (Ruby) application will try to allocate memory after exceeding 150mb ram, at which point (when defining: `limit rss 157286400 157286400`) it would raise an exception (in Ruby's case after doing some research, I think this exception would be raised: `Errno::ENOMEM`) and would crash the process, usually. Probably not in the Rails framework though. I'll have to look in to that. Thanks! I think I'll be able to figure out the rest thanks to your answer!

Comment: Did you find out how this would work with ruby/rails? I'm very interested in trying this out for our service arch.

Comment: @jnewland any progress with the rails app?

Comment: I recently tried to implement this and discovered that the rss limit was not having any effect. From `man 2 getrlimit`: "RLIMIT_RSS               Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident set (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM).  This limit only has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there only affects calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED."

I ended up using `limit as <soft> <hard>`, which caused my runaway process to receive an `ENOMEM`.

Comment: @MichaelHale what does "as" mean, instead of using "rss"?  I too am having problems getting it working but can't find any docs on upstart limit stanza terms...

Answer (score 4):

From the Upstart docs, the limits come from the `rlimit` system call options. (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#limit)

Since Linux 2.4+ setting the rss (Resident Set Size) has no effect.

An alternative already suggested in other answers is **as** which sets the virtual memory Address Space size limits. This will have a very different effect of setting 'real' memory limits.

```
limit as <soft limit> <hard limit>
```

Excerpt from man pages for setrlimit:

> RLIMIT_AS
>                 The maximum size of the process's virtual memory (address space) in bytes.  This limit affects calls to brk(2), mmap(2), and mremap(2),
>                 which fail with the error ENOMEM upon exceeding this limit.  Also automatic stack expansion will fail  (and  generate  a  SIGSEGV  that
>                 kills  the  process  if  no alternate stack has been made available via sigaltstack(2)).  Since the value is a long, on machines with a
>                 32-bit long either this limit is at most 2 GiB, or this resource is unlimited.